# How to open Gmail compose with predefined message body with HTML content

Tags: react-native, gmail, expo

Is there a way to open Android (or iOS) Gmail app in compose mode, with predefined message body that can contain HTML (mainly links).

If I try to open url scheme `mailto:RECIPIENT?subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY` it sure opens Gmail if it's your default email client, but all HTML tags shows in the message body as HTML tags and not formatted text.

I tried `expo-intent-launcher` package, but I can only get Gmail app open. I don't find any info about what intent and params I should try to open it in compose mode:

```js
const activityAction = 'android.intent.action.MAIN' // Intent.ACTION_MAIN
const intentParams: IntentLauncher.IntentLauncherParams = {
    flags: 268435456, // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    category: 'android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL', // Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL
}

IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(activityAction, intentParams)
```

My project uses React Native with Expo. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pure JavaScript function for that using the params `subject` and `body` with a `mailto:`

⚠️ `subject` and `body` in the right format with something like [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Example:

```js
  const composeEmail = () => {
    const email = `mailto:${supportEmail}?subject=${subject}&body=${body}`;
    Linking.openURL(email).catch((error) =>
      console.error("composeEmail -> error", error)
    );
  };
```

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={composeEmail}
>
  <Text>Contact-us</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```